# ¿Como separar items de un slider slick en react?

Tags: css, reactjs, slider, slick-carousel

me encuentro usando react slick para crear un carrusel de tarjetas y no he podido hacer que las tarjetas obtengan el ancho que deseo y siempre aparecen pegadas aunque intente darles margen.
No se que clase de estilo tenga que darle para que las tarjetas aparezcan separadas una de otra.
Este es el codigo utilizado:

**React**

```html
const settings = {
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    nextArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
    prevArrow: <SampleNextArrow />,
    autoplay: true,
    
  };
  return (
    <div>
    <h2> Multiple items </h2>
    <Slider {...settings} className="slider">
    <div className={`card`}>
                <span className={`favorite-brand`}>♥</span>
                <img
                    src="he-man.jpg"
                    alt=""
                />
                <div className={`description-container`}>
                    <span className={`product-name`}>Titulo del Producto</span>
                    <div className={`description-container__price-container`}>
                        <span className={`price`}>$1000</span>
                        <span className={`discount`}>Oferta </span>
                        <span className={`discount`}>90%</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className={`rise-text`}>
                        <span>Texto emergente</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ...continuan divs para replicar las tarjetas...
    </Slider>
  </div>
  );
```

**CSS**

```css
.slider{
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img{
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
.card{
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000; 
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 0px #000000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transition: 1s;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 25px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
.favorite-brand{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.description-container{
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* padding: 0.5rem; */
}
.description-container__price-container{
  flex-direction: row;
}
.product-name{
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.price{
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.discount{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #F00000;
}
.rise-text{
  font-size: 1.3rem;
text-decoration:line-through;
color: gray;
transition: 1s;
background-color: white;
}
```

Al ejecutar se ve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera que las tarjetas tuvieran una separacion entre ellas como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, gracias por sus respuestas, posiblemente este problemo sea mas facil de solucionar de lo que pienso pero es la primera vez que uso una herramienta como react-slick y no se si lo este haciendo correctamente o exista una mejor alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

En este enlace estan distintas manera de hacer esto:
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999076/how-add-spaces-between-slick-carousel-item)

Basicamente es acceder a clases propias de react-slick-carusel y aplicar la separacion con margenes de esta manera.

```css
  /* the slides */
  .slick-slide {
      margin: 0 27px;
  }

  /* the parent */
  .slick-list {
      margin: 0 -27px;
  }
```